# Where can I find the SocialDriverConstants class for this sample code?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Here I have a code of adding a user programmatically. In the code there is `SocialDriverConstants` in line 5 & 6 which is a class,so if anyone has a code for that class then please share. This code is found in the Liferay blogs of James Falkner. The code is:

```
public synchronized static User addUser(String firstName, long companyId,
                                   String themeId, boolean profileFlag)
throws Exception {

 String lastName = getRndStr(SocialDriverConstants.LAST_NAMES);
 String job = getRndStr(SocialDriverConstants.JOB_TITLES);
 Group guestGroup = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(
     companyId, GroupConstants.GUEST);

long[] groupIds;
try {
    // see if there's a demo sales group, and add the user to the
    // group if so
    Group salesGroup = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(
        companyId, "Sales");
    groupIds = new long[]{guestGroup.getGroupId(),
        salesGroup.getGroupId()};
} catch (Exception ex) {
    groupIds = new long[]{guestGroup.getGroupId()};
}
ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();

long[] roleIds;
try {
    // see if we're using social office, and add SO's role to the new
    // user if so
    roleIds = new long[]{RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId,
        "Social Office User").getRoleId()};
    serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(guestGroup.getGroupId());
} catch (Exception ignored) {
    roleIds = new long[]{};
}
User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(UserLocalServiceUtil
    .getDefaultUserId(companyId), companyId, false,
    firstName,
    firstName,
    false, firstName.toLowerCase(), firstName.toLowerCase() +
    "@liferay.com", 0, "",
    LocaleUtil.getDefault(), firstName,
    "", lastName, 0, 0, true, 8, 15, 1974, job, groupIds,
    new long[]{}, roleIds, new long[]{},
    false, serviceContext);

    assignAddressTo(user);
    setFirstLogin(firstName, user);
    assignRandomFriends(user);


    if (profileFlag) {
        setupUserProfile(companyId, themeId, guestGroup, user);
    }
    return user;
}
```

Where can I find that class?

Answer (score 0):

It probably makes more sense to comment on [James' blog article](https://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) (as someone else already did, check the comments there) rather than in an unrelated place, e.g. stackoverflow. He's more likely to read the comments to his own blog articles than elsewhere on the internet.

That being said, it should be really easy to come up with replacements to that class, based on the assumptions of what the code you post uses it for, namely generating random names/jobtitles. Just generate any random stuff for them, so that the API where they're used (in this case: `addUser`) is satisfied